# OpenCV display video without miss and tearing

Tags: opencv, synchronization, vsync

I apologize for my English.

I need to display video frame by frame without tearing with fixed FPS.
(Display work in 50p mode and i want to display 50 different frame per second).

I use soft timer, but nothing works (Stroboscope effect).

I use cv::imshow without OpenGL.

Please, tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a `waitKey(20);` call right after imshow. 20 is the number of ms to wait after displaying an image.

Note, however, that waitKey doesn't guarantee it will return right after the 20th ms ends. It guarantees only that it will be running for at least 20 ms.

If you need something more reliable (it may be the case, since your fps is pretty high), you should employ some high precision clock counter. Like [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html) on linux. Not sure, but I think on Windows it's [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: My system is not real-time, so waitkey gives nothing for syncronisation. I'm trying to get something like veritcal blank signal, but i don't know how, because modern graphics cards do not support access to low-level information.